# Использование переменных при Ajax в WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

Есть страница, на которой вывожу штук 20 постов.

ID этих постов вставляю в массив `$do_not_duplicate`. При следующем цикле использую данный массив, чтобы отсеять уже выведенные посты, чтобы не было дубликатов. Для этого в цикле добавляю параметр `post__not_in`.

Если делать стандартно на одной и той же странице, то всё работает.

Но при создании `Ajax` в `functions.php`, переменная `$do_not_duplicate` оказывается пустой. Я пытаюсь достать её через ключевое слово `global`, но она пустая...

И в итоге, у меня 20 постов вывелись обычным циклом. И потом эти же самые 20 постов выводятся уже через Ajax. Как мне достать всё это в Ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо понимать, что php на сервере работает по принципу "выстрелил и забыл". После вывода страницы на экран все переменные уничтожаются, память освобождается. Вы никак не "достанете" из ajax переменную, которая существовала при генерации страницы.

Вам нужно передать значение вашей переменной (массив) в ajax с помощью wp_localize_script(), а потом передать её назад на сервер в вызове ajax. На сервере в обработчике ajax использовать в post__not_in, добавить в этот массив вновь полученные посты и снова передать в js. И так далее.

Подробности о wp_localize_script() можно прочитать [здесь](https://wp-kama.ru/id_2018/ajax-v-wordpress.html).

Comment: Сделал через localize, но вместо массива приходит null. Я добавил код вверху в своём вопросе. Посмотрите, пожалуйста. Функция admin_url сработала нормально, а массива так и нет...

Comment: Так конечно. Переменная у вас не инициализирована. Вам надо в wp_enqueue_script указывать запуск скрипта в footer. А то у вас такая последовательность: Сначала в header вставляется localize_script (CDATA, посмотрите в коде страницы), а потом вы выводите тело страницы с постами, и заполняете массив $do_not_duplicate.

Comment: Добавил вывод в footer, но результат всё равно отрицательный. Вверху обновил код. Странная штука получается... localizedData.url он же как-то увидел, а вот именно localizedData.ids он в упор не хочет видеть.

Comment: Я использую url: localizedData.url в Ajax для указание PHP обработчика. И всё работает. А localizedData.ids при таких же условиях не видит.

Comment: Я добавил вверху Ajax запрос для примера.

Comment: Вот строка, которую вставляет localize в footer через CDATA:
var localizedData = {"url":"https:\/\/site.com\/wp-admin\/admin-ajax.php","ids":null};

Comment: Где у вас объявление `global $do_not_duplicate;` в начальном цикле, без ajax?

Comment: Эту переменную создаю в самом начале страницы перед обычным циклом: $do_not_duplicate = []; А потом уже в localize пытаюсь достать этот массив с помощью global.

Comment: Она объявлена "в самом начале страницы" как global? Второй раз спрашиваю.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89054/discussion-between-kagg-design-and-lexxy).